# Port forwarding in chrome canary

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have HTML file which is running on xampp server. I want to debug those HTML files in android chrome as well. So I downloaded chrome canary which grant me access to debug on live site. Am I doing something wrong in there

But when I am trying to access my localhost URL it is not working. I tried as follow

1. I put URL http://localhost/HTML/index.html and result is

[image]

2. Then I use port forwarding in chrome canary which is as follow

[image]

3. and after the I put URL http://localhost:8888/HTML/index.html which says no data received.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem - "No data received". This tells me the port forwarding worked but server wasn't returning anything to the debugger.

It worked after I added the port (8888) to IIS site bindings as per the screenshot [image]. Maybe you can give that a try in XAMP.

Good luck.